# I am having issues validating a form, and preventing blank submits. - Only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am having issues with my form. It keeps submitting blank spaces, and I don't know why it's not working.

Any suggestions? I tried other code but it wouldn't work for some reason, but it work in JsFIDDLE.

THANKS!

Can someone help? Here is my code:

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html lang="en">
              <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
              <title>Smart Relief Rx - See if your insurance&#39;s prescription plan covers non-narcotic pain relief</title>
              <!-- Bootstrap -->
              <link href="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
              <link href="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
              <!-- Bootstrap Validator -->
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/css/bootstrapValidator.css"/>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://smartreliefrx.com/pain-relief-offer/style-second.css"/>
              <script src="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

          <script>
          var getParamValue = (function() {
                   var params;
                   var resetParams = function() {
                           var query = window.location.search;
                           var regex = /[?&;](.+?)=([^&;]+)/g;
                           var match;

                           params = {};

                           if (query) {
                               while (match = regex.exec(query)) {
                                   params[match[1]] = decodeURIComponent(match[2]);
                               }
                           }    
                       };

                   window.addEventListener
                   && window.addEventListener('popstate', resetParams);

                   resetParams();

                   return function(param) {
                       return params.hasOwnProperty(param) ? params[param] : null;
                   }

               })();​
          </script>

          <script>
          function MM_validateForm() { //v4.0
          if (document.getElementById){
          var i,p,q,nm,test,num,min,max,errors='',args=MM_validateForm.arguments;
          for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) { test=args[i+2]; val=document.getElementById(args[i]);
            if (val) { nm=val.name; if ((val=val.value)!="") {
              if (test.indexOf('isEmail')!=-1) { p=val.indexOf('@');
                if (p<1 || p==(val.length-1)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain an e-mail address.\n';
              } else if (test!='R') { num = parseFloat(val);
                if (isNaN(val)) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number.\n';
                if (test.indexOf('inRange') != -1) { p=test.indexOf(':');
                  min=test.substring(8,p); max=test.substring(p+1);
                  if (num<min || max<num) errors+='- '+nm+' must contain a number between '+min+' and '+max+'.\n';
            } } } else if (test.charAt(0) == 'R') errors += '- '+nm+' is required.\n'; }
          } if (errors) alert('The following error(s) occurred:\n'+errors);
          document.MM_returnValue = (errors == '');
      } }
              </script>
              <!-- Fonts -->
              <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
              <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
              <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
              <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
              <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
              <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
              <![endif]-->
          </head>

          <body id="home">
          <noscript><center>Please enable JavaScript or use an updated browser! Thanks!</center></noscript>
              <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="navbar-header">
                          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
                          <a target="_BLANK" class="navbar-brand" href="http://smartreliefrx.com">
                              <img src="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/img/logo-white-text.png" alt="" class="nav-logo"/>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <!--<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                              <li><a target="_blank" href="http://smartreliefrx.com/about-cc.html">Learn About Custom Compounds</a></li>
                              <li><a target="_blank" href="http://smartreliefrx.com/speak-to-a-doctor.html">Speak to a Doctor</a></li>
                              <li><a target="_blank" href="http://smartreliefrx.com/getting-started/contact.html">Get Started</a></li>
                          </ul>-->
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row"><div style="font-weight: +20%;">
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
                          <h1>You&#39;re Almost There! Only a few last questions about your Insurance Plan...</h1>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
                          <h5><b>Please make sure you have your Insurance Card handy, you'll need it to complete the following questions.</b></h5>
                      </div></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
                      <form method="POST" action="https://vanillasoft.net/web/post.aspx" name="MyForm" id="MyForm" onSubmit="if (this.email.value == '' || this.firstName.value == '') {return false;}">
                      <div class="input-field">
                        <select name="insuranceType" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputLarge-select" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO" style="color:#0d5973 !important;">
                         <option disabled alue="Please Choose an Insurance" selected>Please Choose an Insurance Type</option
                         ><option value="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/not-qualified.html">Medicare</option>
                         <option value="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/not-qualified.html">Medicaid</option>
                         <option value="#">Private Insurance</option>
                        </select>
                       </div>
                          <p>
                              <input name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-name" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" size="33" maxlength="50">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="LastName" type="text" class="form-control form-control-name" id="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" size="33" maxlength="50">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control form-control-email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" size="33" maxlength="50">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" size="10">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input type="hidden" name="SUB_1" value="">
                          </p> 
                          <p>
                              <input type="hidden" name="AFFILIATE_ID" value="">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="birthdate" type="text" class="form-control form-control-name" id="birthdate" placeholder="Birthdate" size="33">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="address" type="text" class="form-control form-control-email" id="address" placeholder="Address" size="33">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="city" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="city" placeholder="City" style="margin-top: 20px!important;" size="33">
                          </p>
                          <div class="form-group">

                          <p><div class="input-field" name="state">
                       <select value="State" name="state" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputLarge-select" style="height: 40px!important; margin-top: 20px!important; color:#0d5973 !important;">
                       <option value="">Please Choose a State:</option>
                         <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                         <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>      
                         <option value="California">California</option>         
                         <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>       
                         <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>          
                         <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>       
                         <option value="District Of Columbia">District Of Columbia</option>                   
                         <option value="Florida">Florida</option>      
                         <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>      
                         <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>       
                         <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>      
                         <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                         <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>       
                         <option value="Maine">Maine</option>    
                         <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>       
                         <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>            
                         <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>       
                         <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>        
                         <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>       
                         <option value="Montana">Montana</option>      
                         <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>       
                         <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>            
                         <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>         
                         <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>         
                         <option value="New York">New York</option>       
                         <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>             
                         <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>           
                         <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>   
                         <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>       
                         <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>           
                         <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>           
                         <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>             
                         <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>        
                         <option value="Texas">Texas</option>    
                         <option value="Utah">Utah</option>   
                         <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>       
                         <option value="Washington">Washington</option>         
                         <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>            
                         <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>                                          
                         </select>       
                 </div>
                          </p>

                          <p>
                              <input name="zip" type="text" class="form-control form-control-email" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" size="33" maxlength="5">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="insuranceComp" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="insuranceComp" placeholder="Insurance Company" size="33" maxlength="30">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="memberID" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="memberID" placeholder="Member ID or Policy Number" size="33">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="RxBin" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="RxBin" placeholder="RX BIN Number" size="33">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="PcnNumber" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="PcnNumber" placeholder="PCN Number" size="33">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="groupID" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="groupID" placeholder="RX Group Number" size="33">
                          </p>
                          <p>
                              <input name="insurancePhone" type="text" class="form-control form-control-phone" id="insurancePhone" placeholder="Insurance Phone Number" maxlength="10" size="10">
                          </p>
                              <input type="submit" class="btn pi-btn col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8" id="" placeholder="Submit" style="background-color:#009ca8!important;color: #FFF!important;" onClick="MM_validateForm('firstName','','R','LastName','','R','email','','RisEmail','phone','','RisNum','birthdate','','R','address','','R','city','','R','zip','','RisNum','insuranceComp','','R','memberID','','R','RxBin','','R','PcnNumber','','R','groupID','','R','insurancePhone','','RisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Submit">
                          </p>
                        </form>
                                         <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
              function FillForm() {
              // Specify form's name between the quotes on next line.
              var FormName = "MyForm";
              var questionlocation = location.href.indexOf('?');
              if(questionlocation < 0) { return; }
              var q = location.href.substr(questionlocation + 1);
              var list = q.split('&');
              for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                 var kv = list[i].split('=');
                 if(! eval('document.'+FormName+'.'+kv[0])) { continue; }
                 kv[1] = unescape(kv[1]);
                 if(kv[1].indexOf('"') > -1) {
                    var re = /"/g;
                    kv[1] = kv[1].replace(re,'\\"');
                    }
                 eval('document.'+FormName+'.'+kv[0]+'.value="'+kv[1]+'"');
                 }
              }
        FillForm();
        //-->
       </script>
                           </p>
                           <p>&nbsp;

                           </p>
                           <br>
                           <br>
                           <center>
           <a target="_BLANK" href="https://www.facebook.com/SmartReliefRx"><img src="http://smartreliefrx.com/diabetes/facebook.png" style="text-alignment: center!important;" width="50" style=""></a>
           <br>

            <a target="_BLANK" href="https://www.facebook.com/SmartReliefRx" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial;">Find us on Facebook!</a><br/>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
            <a target="_BLANK" href="http://www.smartreliefrx.com/pain-relief-offer/privacy-policy.html" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_BLANK"href="http://www.smartreliefrx.com/pain-relief-offer/terms.html" style="color: #FFF; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial;">Terms and Agreement</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
           </div>
           <p>
              </div>
              <script src="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
              <!-- Bootstrap -->
              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
              <!-- Bootstrap Validator -->
              <script type="text/javascript" src="http://smartreliefrx.com/qualify/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
          </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are trying to do. Some of your code seems generated by Dreamweaver and is pretty much unreadable. But seeing that you flagged this question with jquery, I recommend taking a look at http://jqueryvalidation.org/.

Comment: Some of it is from dreamweaver because nothing else was working. Now I have a mess of code, but I want to clean it up, and make all fields required, and not allow empty fields to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers can support **required** attribute in each input fields like this.

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" required />
```

The browser will catch it for you even without any javascript.